# Why is my discord bot taking so long to research videos

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Basically my bot is taking too long to send me the results for the video research he made on youtube. I do believe that the problem is in this `for` loop, but I'm not sure about it

```
        for(var i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
            //Search for video
            const videoFinder = async (query) => {
                const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

                return (videoResult.videos.length > (i + 1)) ? videoResult.videos[i] : null;
            }
            const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));

            if(video){
                searchResults.push(video)            
            } else {
                searchResults.push('No video results found');
            }

        }
```

This is the entire code to the play command:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core')
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
const { User } = require('discord.js');
const { accessSync } = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: "Plays video from youtube on a earrape mode",
    async execute(client, message, args){
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
        
        //Check if person is in voice chat
        if(!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a voice chat to execute this command');
        //Check person permissions
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT' || 'SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the permission to execute this command');
        //Check if message has arguments
        if(!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send some keywords')

        var searchResults = [];

        //Bot join VC
        const connection = await voiceChannel.join();

        for(var i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
            //Search for video
            const videoFinder = async (query) => {
                const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

                return (videoResult.videos.length > (i + 1)) ? videoResult.videos[i] : null;
            }
            const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));

            if(video){
                searchResults.push(video)               
            } else {
                searchResults.push('No video results found');
            }

        }

        let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id


        var whichVideo = null;

        await message.channel.send({embed: {
            color: 3447003,
            title: "Select your music:",
            fields: [
                {
                    name: `1.`,
                    value: `***[${searchResults[0].title}](${searchResults[0].url})***`
                },
                {
                    name: `2.`,
                    value: `***[${searchResults[1].title}](${searchResults[1].url})***`
                },
                {
                    name: `3.`,
                    value: `***[${searchResults[2].title}](${searchResults[2].url})***`
                },
                {
                    name: `4.`,
                    value: `***[${searchResults[3].title}](${searchResults[3].url})***`
                },
                {
                    name: `5.`,
                    value: `***[${searchResults[4].title}](${searchResults[4].url})***`
                }
            ],
            footer: {
                icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
                text: "Timeout in 30 seconds"
            }
          }
        })
        .then(() => {
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                max: 1,
                time: 30000,
                errors: ['time']
            })
            .then(message => {
                message = message.first();
                if (message.content == '1' || message.content == '2' || message.content == '3' || message.content == '4' || message.content == '5'){
                    whichVideo = parseInt(message.content) - 1;
                    message.channel.send(`:musical_note: added ~ ***${searchResults[whichVideo].title}*** ~ to the queue`);      
        
                    try{

                        message.channel.send(`:loud_sound: :notes: Now Playing: ~ ***${searchResults[whichVideo].title}*** ~`);

                        //Get only the audio of the video
                        const stream = ytdl(searchResults[whichVideo].url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
            
                        //Bot joins plays music
                        connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
                        
                        //Leave when music ends
                        .on('finish', () =>{
                            voiceChannel.leave();
                        });
                        
                    } catch (e){
                        console.log(e);
                        voiceChannel.leave();
                    }

                } else {
                    message.channel.send('');
                }
            })
            .catch(collected => {
                message.channel.send('');
            });
        })

        


        
    }
}
```

Comment: Try putting some checkpoints in your code so you can identify which part of your script is taking the longest time. See this for JavaScript's time functions: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I think the issue is in this part:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
            //Search for video
            const videoFinder = async (query) => {
                const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

                return (videoResult.videos.length > (i + 1)) ? videoResult.videos[i] : null;
            }
            const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));

            if(video){
                searchResults.push(video)               
            } else {
                searchResults.push('No video results found');
            }

        }
```

You are launching 4 searches (?)
Try using this library instead:

```
var search = require('youtube-search');

var opts = {
  maxResults: 4,
  key: 'Your YouTube API V3 key'
};

search('video title', opts, function(err, results) {
  if(err) return console.log(err);

  console.dir(results);
});
```

This way you can search for 4 results at the same time, this should speed up your process.